# Is there a way to produce migration script for postgresql using Script-Migration in asp.net core 5

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

After adding migrations in a code first approach,
when i need to apply changes to production database (postgresql 13), i need to generate script for those changes.

> script-migration

from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs)
generates sql script for SQL Server.
but i need it for postgresql.
there is an online [tool](http://www.sqlines.com/online) that converts SQL server script to Postgresql but introduces errors.
Is there a way to produce postgresql script automatically? As i am not very confident with postgresql syntax.

Comment: Do you have a Postgresql-Connection in your Application?

Comment: Look at this [tutorial](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) maybe it helps.

Comment: @Nikolaus yes, i have postgresql-connection using this "Npgsql Entity Framework Core Provider" and yes this tutorial is exactly what i have done.
the problem is that i cannot generate migration scripts for postgresql.

Comment: Does it work with Update-Database?

Comment: If it works with Update-Database, I'd suggest to open a new issue on [Github](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg)

Comment: Yes, it works with update-database. Thanks. I will @Nikolaus

Comment: Please let others know, If there are News.

Comment: opened an issue.
https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1846

Answer (score 1):

Shay Rojansky from the npgsql team mentioned "The typical way is to maintain a set of migrations for each provider, and at that point you can generate SQL migration scripts for the provider you want."
This link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli
provides the details for using multiple providers.
And i was missing the
--project
and
--provider
parameters when adding migrations and i needed to maintain a set of migrations for each provider.
And
in case you have only one provider enabled (with one db context) like [this](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/), scipt-migration command will create script for it.